glmnet() result differs when using `weights` argument and when using manually transformed data
In order to weight observations when performing lasso, a convenient way is to specify the weights argument in glmnet(). In addition, from the perspective of loss function, one can also transform x and y first and get the same result. The weighted loss function is

In OLS (using lm()), the equality of these two ways have been verified (see here and here).
However, when it comes to lasso (using glmnet()), I can't get the same results. The results are similar but not identical. Is there anything special in glmnet() when observations are weighted?
library(glmnet)

# generate data
set.seed(0)
x <- matrix(rnorm(20*10), 20, 10)
beta <- c(rep(0.5, 5), rep(0, 5))
y <- x %*% beta + rnorm(20)

# transform data manually
weight <- c(rep(1.5, 12), rep(0.3, 4), rep(0.2, 4))
weight_sqrt_matrix <- diag(sqrt(weight))
x_weighted <- weight_sqrt_matrix %*% cbind(1, x)
y_weighted <- weight_sqrt_matrix %*% y

# perform lasso in two different ways
model1 <- glmnet(x, y, weights=weight) # using `weights` argument
model2 <- glmnet(x_weighted, y_weighted, intercept=FALSE) # using manually transformed data
print(coef.glmnet(model1, s=0.1, exact=TRUE, x=x, y=y, weights=weight))
print(coef.glmnet(model2, s=0.1, exact=TRUE, x=x_weighted, y=y_weighted))

# 11 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# s1
# (Intercept) 0.141692116
# V1          0.231520492
# V2          0.026418923
# V3          .          
# V4          0.745387658
# V5          0.360818388
# V6          0.016499710
# V7          .          
# V8          .          
# V9          0.514858361
# V10         0.007955152


# 12 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# s1
# (Intercept) .         
# V1          0.09617875
# V2          0.22991659
# V3          0.01695526
# V4          .         
# V5          0.73183147
# V6          0.37464778
# V7          0.01843960
# V8          .         
# V9          .         
# V10         0.52352742
# V11         0.02551741

# the estimation results are identical when using (W)OLS
model1 <- lm(y ~ x, weights=weight)
model2 <- lm(y_weighted ~ x_weighted - 1)
print(all(coef(model1) == coef(model2)))
# [1] TRUE

Update
Inspired by this question, it seems that we should center x and y first if setting intercept=FALSE. This makes the results closer, but the discrepancy still exist.
Related question:
R: lm() result differs when using `weights` argument and when using manually reweighted data
